# Directory quotas on Windows Server

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization

We're developing a SaaS application which, among other things, provides space for Mercurial (Hg) repositories. Now, Hg repo is just a directory on a disk and each user is allowed to have as many of them as possible, but the limiting factor here is the amount of disk space allocated based on their subscription (like, 100 Mb for Free plan, 6 Gb for Premium, etc).

What we're trying to do is to have per-directory quotas for *one* user (which will be the user ASP.NET site will be running under). Is this doable under Windows Server? If it is, can it be done programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is possible -- see [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/07/01/434790.aspx): *New feature in Windows Server 2003 R2: directory-level quotas*. However this seems to only act on the folder, and not a folder-user pairing, but you may be able to use this in conjunction with the per-user quota (that acts at the volume level) somehow.